# The Crawl DB size now comes to 130GB - Performance tunning

Tags: search, enterprise-search

The Crawl DB size now comes to 130GB and PropertyStore is 32GB. Is it ok to change the Recovery Model to 'Simple' and the Auto shrink property to 'True' also shall we truncate the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this, I don't know of and I haven't found a reason why not to for large crawl databases (50GB+)